# Windows exporer crashes whenever I select a specific file

Tags: window, file-corruption

Windows explorer keeps crashing when I attempt to select a specific file. The file is a .STL file (stereo lithography, a 3D CAD file format) and was freshly generated from a program i was writing (the file is undoubtedly corrupted, mangled inside my program before it got spat out).

Any idea on how I can delete it? I can't even select it right now.

Currently using windows 7 64-bit

Comment: You may be able to delete it in safe mode if the command line is not your cup of tea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Command Prompt, navigate to the directory containing the file using the `cd` command and type:

```
DEL filename.ext
```

This command deletes the file directly, without moving it to the Recycle Bin. Replace `filename.ext` with the actual filename.  If the name contains a space, use double quotes `"` to surround the name.